# Determine the radius of Convergence of this telescoping series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Can anyone point it out how to find the radius of convergence of this series?

$\sum_{n= 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(x+n) \cdot (x+n - 1)}$

I tried the Ratio Test, but the limit goes to 1.

Any help is appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: That is not a power series, but it is a telescopic series, equal to $\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: What is the meaning of radius of convergence outside the context of power series?

Comment: The ratio test only applies to power series, is that what you guys are trying to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be rewritten as:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{x+n}-\frac{1}{x+n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{x+1}$$

Since it's a telescopic series and not a power one, this is always convergent (for every real $x \neq -1$).

As @Doug M noticed, $x$ cannot be a negative integer since the sum is not bounded.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see it! Thank you very much. I wouldn't have realized that little tricky :)

Comment: Will do! In.. three minutes :D

Comment: Suppose $x$ is a negative integer other than $-1$ then the series will be undefined, even if the limits exist approaching each of these negative integers.

Comment: The problem is not whether the sum is unbounded for negative integers. It’s that some of the terms will not even be defined because we divide by zero, so the sum makes no sense in those cases.